# match first table to second table and copy corresponding information from second table in to first table using R

Tags: r, join, merge

I want to extract information from column species of reference table and add it to column species of table1

```
a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(2001,NA,NA,2004,2005,NA,2007,NA,2009,2010)
c <- c('A','B',NA,'D','E','F','G','H',NA,NA)
table1 <- data.frame(serial=a, id=b, species=c)

e <- c(2001:2010)
f <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J')
reference_table <- data.frame(id=e, species=f)
```

I want to have two different outputs

Output 1 -where in column species row9 and 10 got I and J resp., while NA at 3rd row was retained

```
#table1
#Serial  id  species
# 1     2001   A
# 2     NA     B
# 3     NA     NA
# 4     2004   D
# 5     2005   E
# 6     NA     F
# 7     2007   G
# 8     NA     H
# 9     2009   I
# 10    2010   J
```

Output 2 - where in column id row 2nd,6th and 8th got 2002,2006 and 2008 resp.

```
#table1
#Serial  id  species
# 1     2001   A
# 2     2002   B
# 3     NA     NA
# 4     2004   D
# 5     2005   E
# 6     2006   F
# 7     2007   G
# 8     2008   H
# 9     2009   I
# 10    2010   J
```

Comment: Did you attempt a `merge()` at all yet? What exactly is the problrm you are running into?

Comment: @MrFlick My original table1 is 9460 by 47, when I used merge(x = table1, y = reference_table, by = "ID", all = TRUE), i got output of 10million rows

Comment: Well, you probably don't want `all=T`. You are going to want `all.x=T` or `all.y=T` for a left or right join.

Comment: @MrFlick now I have used all.x =T it gave me 1000 rows more than original table, in case of all.y =T that gave me 1600 rows less than original table

Comment: Do you happen to have duplicates?

Comment: @sotos, yes the reference table consist of unique 77 species and their corresponding IDs. In table1 there are different experimental results using same species. So lets say for species RAT there are more than 2000 rows. On top of that there are NA.

Answer (score 0):

I used MySQL

```
UPDATE table1 AS a JOIN reference_table AS b ON a.species = b.species SET a.id = b.id

UPDATE table1 AS a JOIN reference_table AS b ON a.id= b.id SET a.species  = b.species
```